# How can I implement this kind of layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I just want to implement this kind of layout and I have no idea about how this layout is design. I am working on web browser so for showing web tabs I want to implement this.

Also, should I implement tab using fragment and viewPage's FragmentStatePagerAdapter method?

[image]

[image]

So these tabs can be deleted upon swiping up them.

### Edit

If this is achievable using ViewPager then can anyone give me some guide or link to achieve this. I know how to work with fragment but I don't know how I can zoom out of fragment (like when we get out of Chrome's web tabs). How can I implement this zoom_Out_Of_Fragment kind of thing?

### Edit 2

After doing some google search, I found that these are actually recyclerView adapter.

Comment: One on the left - `BottomNavigation` with `ViewPager`. One on the right - `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. Then in the `ViewPager` add swipe up/down gesture detection to delete/remove items.

Comment: Or the one on the right could just be a `ViewPager` inside a fragment/activity

Comment: can we just zoom out from fragments in the ViewPager. Like in the 2nd app on pressing a button this view is visible and then i can navigate to any webpage and then on clicking that webpage the fragment is shown completely. (2nd image is of Redmi Browser).

Comment: @HB can you elaborate how can i achieve this layout using ViewPager.